# having troubles installing mongoDB in codeanywhere

Tags: mongodb, web-deployment, web-development-server, codeanywhere

I am having troubles installing mongoDB in codeanywhere. It generally shows..

```
cabox@box-codeanywhere:~/workspace$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2930ADAE8CAF5059EE73BB4B58712A2291FA4AD5
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.i9L1IwAn0P --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/
trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2930ADAE8CAF5059EE73BB4B58712A2291FA4AD5
gpg: requesting key 91FA4AD5 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 91FA4AD5: "MongoDB 3.6 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
cabox@box-codeanywhere:~/workspace$ echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d
/mongodb-org-3.6.list
deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse
cabox@box-codeanywhere:~/workspace$ sudo apt-get update
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found.
N: Is the package apt-transport-https installed?
cabox@box-codeanywhere:~/workspace$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
Reading package lists... 1%
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org
```

help me please

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the main problem is that the repo uses https, hence `Is the package apt-transport-https installed?`

Try installing apt-transport-https before adding any https repos and see if that helps.

I did this by simply destroying my container, creating a new one (Node.js on Ubuntu), running `sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https`, then `sudo apt-get update` and then doing the instructions on [this page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) as you were attempting to do so